# How to debug Syncing lock on pushing the current branch to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

Last night I committed to local repo just fine but then when pushing up to Visual Studio Team Services (previously Team Foundation Service, not Server), the commit hangs.

Visual Studio is not locked up but the commit progress bar stopped progressing. I'm trying again this morning but to no avail.

It just says Syncing - pushing the current branch. Progress bar is about 75%.

Where can I find the logs for such things? How can I find out what the problem is?